Can I caulk seams in vinyl fascia wrap?
We have a hundred-year-old wooden house that we hope to preserve both practically and aesthetically.
In getting a new roof, we let the guys talk us into a PVC sheet on a flat porch roof. That's fine, but it seems to have come with a vinyl fascia wrap, that has those ugly open corners, where two pieces just meet and hang out side-by-side with no connection, and a few seams. The guys think they are doing a good thing, protecting the wood from water, and they are -- don't want to make them remove it.
Is there anything we can do to make it look less cheesy? Caulk, add a small trim strip?

A picture here would be great.  It would help us understand exactly what your issue is.

If they are just cutting the PVC and having them meet at the corner with no over lap, they are not doing it right. The horizonal piece needs to be cut an inch longer and snipped so it will bend 90 degrees to start up the angle of the roof (rake) and then the PVC covering the rake will lap over that by the 1" turning the corner.

Oh dear, I am pretty sure that (just meet at corner) is exactly what they did. I will try to get a photo.
